# How to run diagnose or restart Bluetooth on Ubuntu?

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

The Bluetooth is working fine, but from time to time, the connection drops and then i cant enable Bluetooth again, like its crashed or something.

This happens now quite some times after my PC comes back from a "Suspend mode", when I reboot Ubuntu it is fixed again.

Are there some commands how to restart it properly after "a crash", or how to run a diagnose what is broken with the Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the status and see what is blocking:

```
rfkill list all
```

If it says blocked by hardware it is likely from a keyboard, bios, kernel module/driver. If blocked by software it is likely from the service.

To start/stop/enable/disable/restart using systemd:

```
sudo systemctl start Bluetooth
sudo systemctl stop Bluetooth
sudo systemctl enable Bluetooth
sudo systemctl disable Bluetooth
sudo systemctl restart Bleutooth
```

or

```
sudo service Bluetooth start
sudo service Bluetooth stop
sudo service Bluetooth enable
sudo service Bluetooth disable
sudo service Bluetooth restart
```

Also possible:

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
rfkill block bluetooth
```